# Как ByteArray преобразовать к DisplayObject для помещения на сцену (addChild())

Tags: flash, actionscript

Имеется массив:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
```

В этом массиве находится `SWF` файл в побайтовом виде.
Необходимо вывести `SWF` файл на сцену: `addChild()` позволяет вывести
объект типа `DisplayObject`.
Как преобразовать `ByteArray` в `DisplayObject`, чтобы его вывести на сцену?

Answer (score 1):

например так:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.loadBytes(...);
addChild(loader);
```